# Estimating a GCD

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution, point-estimation

I have two related questions.

Question 1:  Let $k_1, \ldots k_n$ be positive integers, and $\alpha_1, \ldots \alpha_n \in (0,1)$ be such that $\sum_{j \leq n} \alpha_j = 1$.
Suppose $\langle X_m \rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an iid sequence of random variables such that each $X_i$ takes the value $k_j$ with probability $\alpha_j$.  Suppose we want to estimate $\theta = GCD\{k_1, \ldots k_n\}$, but we know neither $n$ nor the $\alpha_i$s.

For example, suppose $n=3$ and that $k_1 = 4, k_2 = 6,$ and $k_3 = 8$, so that $\theta=2$.  Suppose each $X_m$ takes the value $4$, $6$, and $8$ with equal probability, and assume the $X_m$s are independent.

To me, it seems reasonable to use $\hat{\theta}_j = GCD\{X_1, \ldots X_j\}$.  The estimator is consistent.  Why?  No matter how large $n$ is, for any arbitrarily high probability $1-\epsilon$, there is some sufficiently large sample $N_{\epsilon}$ such that there is greater than $1- \epsilon$ probability that each $k_i$ will have been observed at least once.  Consequently, $\hat{\theta}_{N_{\epsilon}} = \theta$ with probability at least $1 - \epsilon$.

For example, in the above example, there is a $1 - 3 \cdot (2/3)^{10} > 99\%$ chance that $k_1=4, k_2=6,$ and $k_3=8$ will all have been seen after 20 observations.  So $\hat{\theta}_{20} = 2 = \theta$ with probability greater than $99\%$.  Has this problem been studied?

Question 2:  Let $r_1, \ldots r_n$ be positive reals, and $\alpha_1, \ldots \alpha_n \in (0,1)$ be such that $\sum_{j \leq n} \alpha_j = 1$.  Suppose $r_k = k \cdot r_1$ for all $k \leq n$.  As above, suppose we do not know $n$ or the $\alpha_j$s.

Suppose $\langle X_m \rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an iid sequence of random variables such that each $X_i$ has the distribution $\sum_{j \leq n} \alpha_j \cdot N(r_j, \sigma^2)$, i.e., $X_i$'s distribution is a convex combination of normal distributions centered at the various $r_j$s.  Is there a consistent estimator of $r_1$?  If so, what is it?  Has this problem been studied?

Note:  The second question is about estimating the least $r_i$, which is like a GCD in that all other $r_i$s are integral multiples of it by stipulation.

Comment: In your second example, the $X_i$ aren't integers any more, and how they relate to the $k_j$ is unclear.  It seems to me that, in this case, GCD as a concept is of limited applicability.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: The description in question 1 in unclear and perhaps incomplete.  Could you perhaps supplement it with a short, simple illustration of such a sequence of variables?

Comment: I tried to clarify question 1 by giving a simple example.  But the general point is that the $X_m$s are drawn from the same discrete distribution, and that distribution takes only positive integral values.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for feedback on the following potential solution to the second question.  The idea is to use a combination of (1) the EM algorithm and (2) standard model selection techniques (e.g., BIC).

Specifically, for each natural number $k$, let $M_k$ be the set of distributions of the form $\sum_{1 \leq j \leq k} \beta_j \cdot N(j \cdot s, \sigma^2)$ where $s \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$, i.e., $M_k$ contains sums of exactly $k$ many normal distributions.  At each sample size $m$, use the EM algorithm (http://www.cmlab.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cyy/learning/papers/EM_TomasiEM.pdf) to find an approximation to the MLE $\hat{\theta}_{m, k}$ over $M_k$.  Here, $\hat{\theta}_{m, k}$ outputs a $k+1$-dimensional vector, namely, the values of $\beta_1 \ldots \beta_k$ and $s$, which are estimates of $\alpha_1 \ldots \alpha_n$ and $r_1$ under the assumption that $k=n$.  Now use a model selection technique (e.g., Bayesian Information criterion) to select the best model $M_k$.